# Dynamically Create IFrame and Append to unknown parent

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I'm currently creating a widget that would asynchronously load a JS file which in turn would create an IFrame accordingly, my current issue is the location of where the Iframe is created. I need to create the IFrame into the parent node, which is unknown.

The issue is that the JS that is being loaded (wherever it's pasted on the example.html page) is not loading the IFrame within the parent element. I need it to consistently load the IFrame into the parent element of where the JS snippet is pasted.

**example.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uid = "1";
    (function(){
    var m = document.createElement('script');
    m.type = 'text/javascript';
    m.async = 'true';
    m.src = 'http://www.site.com/widget/widget.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(m, s);
})();
</script>
```

**Widget.js**

```
(function createFrame(){
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.id = "jobBoard";

   iframe.width = 100+"%"; 
   iframe.height = 100+"%";
   iframe.frameborder = "0";
   iframe.scrolling = "no";
   iframe.marginheight="0" ;
   iframe.marginwidth="0";
   iframe.frameborder="0"

    iframe.setAttribute("style","width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#FFF; border:none;padding:0 0 0 0; overflow-y: hidden; overflow:; -ms-overflow-y: hidden; -ms-overflow-x: hidden;");
    loc = "http://www.site.com/widget/open-jobs?uid=" + uid;
    iframe.src = loc;

    var scriptTags = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var i = scriptTags.length;
    while (i--) {
    if (scriptTags[i].src.indexOf('site.com') >= 0) {
              alert(scriptTags[i].parentNode)

        scriptTags[i].parentNode.appendChild(iframe);

        i = 0;
    }
    }

})();
```

Comment: Function is giving syntax error...remove `)();` from the end

Comment: Sorry, was missing "(" before function.  It should execute now.

Comment: Yes. It's dummy. The issue is that the async frame creation is just being appended to the BODY sometimes or the DIV or the P... yet never it's actual parent. Wherever the JS script is pasted, I need it to append itself to it's parent.

Comment: Essentially the script get's created in the "example.html" and then it dynamically creates the IFRame. None of these are issues. The issue is the Iframe that is created is not appended to the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.currentScript). Not the greatest support.

Let me whip something up:

[Voila fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/M8FTs/show/) with [external JS](https://rawgithub.com/rudiedirkx/7438589/raw/0b87de47e7fb5044251552fd13967ec41fa9dc0f/iframe.js).

Comment: Thanks for the quick Fiddle, looks good but the browser support on that seems quite lacking :(

There's got to be a heavily supported way to create an Iframe/Div/Etc within the parent of where the JS script is located?

Comment: Not from an external JS.